# nginx proxy_pass serving from default path other than application's

Tags: nginx

I'm running a local web service listening on port 8888

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  dracut.site;

    location /jupyter {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888/;
    }
}
```

When I access `http://dracut.site/jupyter`, nginx is using files under `/etc/nginx` and returns error.

```
"/etc/nginx/html/tree" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Files should be served from the app listening on port 8888, how can I configure it.

Comment: Probably because your server block does not match, e.g. this server block has a `server_name fictional-domain-name.fake` directive, or it does not listen on 80.

Comment: updated the full server block

Answer (score 0):

your desciption is not complete...
you're using static html?
then want nginx to serve it...

just define `root` then location tag to that root

Comment: I'm running a web server in local listening on port 8888, it's not a static html, actually it's python jupyter notebook

Comment: use example.local / example.localhost

Comment: updated description, and `dracut.site` can be resolved to the machine running local web service

Comment: your app serve/need a static content?
if yes, just add
`root /path/to/your/app/directory/html/tree`